# Am I the only one who finds std::move a little too difficult to understand?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

So I have been reading about `std::move`, `std::forward`, rvalues, lvalues ad so on in SO and other places. But I find that I can't grasp it. Even though I sometimes get into fixes, I think I understand basic stuff about pointers, references, etc which were in C++ before all this. Is it me or are these stuff getting too heavy?

Comment: Luckily, you've got about 10 more years to try to understand them before they become standardized.

Comment: What can't you grasp exactly? Granted, rvalues can be a little confusing at first, but the others are pretty straight forward. Of course you can use pointers and references directly if you want, but they can be abused and misused, leading to problems that can be hard to diagnose at times. The standard libraries aim to help you write safer, correct code by allowing more compile-time validations that you might not have otherwise.

Comment: @Travis:  Not really.  C++0x should be standardized next year and some compiler implementations already support them (namely Visual C++ and g++, though others may support them already too).

Comment: @James: Your optimism is so heart-warming.  More seriously, though, if you're in the wonderful position where you only have to work with modern compilers, learn this stuff right away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very general. Maybe I can get you started:

- Ignore the functions `std:move()` and `std::forward()` at the beginning
- One aspect of *RValue References* is to save temporaries.

  - In C++03 code, count the temps for `Matrix z = a + b + c + d;` (with `Matrix a,b,c,d;`)
  - implement yourself `operator+` on `Matrix` with overloaded *RValue References*.
  - you should be able to reduce the number of temporaries greatly.

If you want to see a simple use of `std::move()`: Help the compiler to avoid introducing a copy for a return value:

- Make a container class like `Image` -- costly to copy.
- Do not forget to implement the *move* and *copy-assign*
- invent a factory function that works like this:

  ```
  Image load_matching_size(const char *fn_small, const char *fn_big) {
     pair<Image> ii = load_2_images(fn_small, fn_big);
     return ii.first.width() >= 64 ? ii.first : ii.second;
  }
  ```
- Can you count the numbers of temporaries? Note that the `return` will need an additional one and copy! (The example is designed so that *return-value-optimization* ("RVO") should not be possible)
- Can you see that this would not be necessary? The Images in `ii` will be thrown away shorty after the function returned. Could the compiler use then for the return value? (No it could not. RVO would work if we had only one `Image`).
- With `move` in the `return` you can tell the compiler, that you do not need `ii` further and that it can use it for the return. And thus spare a costly copy my using the **move-c'tor** instead of the **copy-c'tor** for the return.

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend reading the original proposal if you haven't already:

> [A Proposal to Add Move Semantics Support to the C++ Language](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1377.htm)

It lays out very clearly the problems that can be solved with rvalue references and move semantics and how rvalue references and move semantics can be used to solve those problems.

Standards committee papers are often dense and difficult to understand, but this one is quite accessible and very much worth reading.  The rvalue references and move semantics as specified in the final C++0x standard (whenever that happens) may be different from what is proposed in this paper, but the concepts are still the same.

Comment: No I haven't read that yet for exactly the same reason you have stated. I find official docs too hard to sift through. Which is why a site like this is so great. But I'll give it a try :(.

Comment: @nakiya:  Feel free to post back here with any questions (or curse at me in a comment if you don't find that paper helpful).  The paper is technical, but from a high enough level that it's readable.